# State-space initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I have a state space system represented by the following system of equations. The state vector is defined by:

$$ \dot{X}\left(t\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}0&1\\a&b\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}0\\1\\\end{matrix}\right]u(t)$$

and the output vector by

$$Y\left(t\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}c&d\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\\\end{matrix}\right]+[e]u(t) $$

I'm wondering how I would impose the initial condition that $  \frac{dY\left(0\right)}{dt}=C$ such that I could represent it in the from $$ x(0)=\left[\begin{matrix}x_{1,o}\\x_{2,o}\\\end{matrix}\right]$$
Let me know if you have any suggestions for how I would do this.

Comment: This will not be possible. Because you cannot write a state-space system for which the derivative of $I$ can be expressed as a proper transfer function from $u$ to $\dot{I}$. This is because of the presence of the nonzero direct feedthrough term.

Comment: The question is not clear: For real-world systems, $e = 0$. The system needs to be redefined. Also, initial conditions are defined in terms of the state vector consisting of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and not on the output function $y(t)$.

Comment: Ok, that's kinda why I was confused before. I was trying to differentiate the output expression but I couldn't get rid of the $V_r$ term or the $\dddot{x} $ term that arises from differentiating. Is there any way around using the direct feedthrough term in this analysis?

Comment: You could just select a controller, e.g., u = -Kx. Then solve for $x(t)$ and plug it into $\dot{y} = (C-K)\dot{x} = (C-K)(A-BK)x$ and compute what the initial conditions need to be ($C=[c\ d]$ and not your initial condition).

Comment: @Dr.Sundar That somehow misses the point. The system could describe a controller which should at some point be re-initialized to a defined state, with a constraint on its output derivative. A controller doesn't need to have $e=0$ and if your system actually has a feedthrough term, you need to express that in the equations.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the required initial conditions just solve the derivative of the output for your desired rate of change. You have:

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= a x_1 + b x_2 + u \\
y &=  c x_1 + d x_2 + e u
\end{align}
$$

So the derivative of the output is

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{y} &= c \dot{x}_1 + d \dot{x}_2 + e \dot{u} \\
&= d (u + a x_1 + b x_2) + c x_2 + \dot{u} e 
\end{align}
$$

So solving $\dot{y} = C$ for $x_1$, $x_2$ provides you some initial conditions:

$$
\begin{align}
x_1(0) &= -\frac{\dot{u}(0) e - C + d u(0)}{a d} \\
x_2(0) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

This choice will guarantee that $\dot{y}(0) = C$, while $a d \neq 0$ is required for this computation.

We can check that by setting for example $a=-2,b=-3,c=2,d=1,e=1,C=-10$. Assume the system input is $u=\sin(2t)$ so that $\dot{u}=2\cos(2t)$ and hence $u(0)=0,\dot{u}(0)=2$. Then a quick simulation gives:

[image]

So you can see that with this choice of initial conditions you can impose any initial output derivative you want.

Of course you need $\dot{u}(0)$ for this computation. If you don't have it available you could do several things to circumvent this problem, like:

- Since you control $u$ demand $u = 0$ during the initialisation, since then $\dot{u} = 0$.
- If your system is stable, use feedforward during initialization so that you can compute $\dot{u}$.
- Approximate $\dot{u}$ with a high pass.
- If $e$ is small, ignore the contribution of $\dot{u}$.

Which one of those (if any) will work for you will depend on your application and the goal you are trying to achieve.